# Schedule Cron/Quartz job immediately

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I want to schedule job that would run immediately once the server is up, but run only once. I am not able to find the valid values to do the same. I tried this: `0/1 ? ? ? ? ?`, but nothing seems to be getting scheduled. Assuming I am correct about the cron format for Quartz i.e `<secs> <mins> <hrs> <dayofmonth> <month> <dayofweek>`

Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cron trigger is an overkill here, use a [`SimpleTrigger`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05) instead:

```
SimpleTrigger trigger = (SimpleTrigger) newTrigger() 
  .startAt(new Date())  //now
  .build();
```